# How to add icon class in PHP form_submit of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <?php  echo form_submit(['type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn login-btn', 'name'=>'btnLogin', 'i class'=>'icon-long-arrow-right' , 'value'=>'Login']); ?>
```

How to display an icon on button in Codeigniter.I tried this but it didn't show icon on button.Where to make change so that icon will displayed on button?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php  echo form_submit('btnLogin', 'Login', '"class"="btn login-btn" "i class"="icon-long-arrow-right"'); ?
```

the first parameter is the `name`, second is the `value` of your button.

Comment: not work correctly only show Login Button with Login name.thanks for your  help....

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'button',
    'id' => 'button',
    'value' => 'true',
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-sm icon-cancel-circle2',
    'content' => '<i class="icon-long-arrow-right"></i>'
);

echo form_button($data);
```

you can use this.Hope it helps.

Comment: not come with an arrow icon all are right but icon didn't come...thanks for help